# Backslashes in values/selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, backslash

I have an HTML (multi)select list containing a list of network devices.

```
<select id="Printers" multiple="multiple" name="Printers">
  <option value="\\ABCDEF01\PRINTER1\">\\ABCDEF01\PRINTER1\</option>
  <option value="\\ABCDEF02\PRINTER2">\\ABCDEF02\PRINTER2</option>
  ...
  ...
</select>
```

I'm wanting to auto select values with javascript.  This is the code I am currently using:

```
//Assume: val.Name == "\\ABCDEF02\PRINTER2"

var select = document.getElementById('Printers');
var escapedName = val.Name.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"); // Escape backslashes.
$("option[value=\"" + escapedName + "\"]", select).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This code works in chrome, but not in IE7.  Is there a quirk I should know about that would prevent this from working correctly on IE7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like working.. with jquery 1.9

http://jsfiddle.net/2nGnm/

html:

```
<select id="Printers" multiple="multiple" name="Printers">
  <option value="\\ABCDEF01\PRINTER1\">\\ABCDEF01\PRINTER1\</option>
  <option value="\\ABCDEF02\PRINTER2">\\ABCDEF02\PRINTER2</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
var select = document.getElementById('Printers');
var escapedName = $('[name="Printers"] option:last').val().replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"); // Escape backslashes.
$('option[value="' + escapedName + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Interestingly... The example works in jsfiddle with jQuery 1.9.0 selected, but not 1.8.3.  I've just updated my project to 1.9.0 and it seems to be working.  I'll test & report back.

Comment: k.. I will check jquery 1.8.3

Comment: Confirmed, working w/ 1.9 but not 1.8.3.  Thank-you for leading me to this solution.